# How to SSH into Pi from Sublime Text

Tags: ssh

I can SSH using terminal. I use a mac.

I've done some research into SSHing into the Pi from Sublime Text Editor. I've downloaded the SFTP plugin, which, in theory, lets me do this. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not very experienced with this sort of linux based stuff and I cannot find ANYTHING on SSHing into a Pi from a third party editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just some friendly advice, responders will need a little more information that this to give a useful answer.  What OS are your running Sublime on?

Comment: I would suggest using sshfs to mount your pi as a normal directory and then open what you need in sublime from that directory

Comment: I've only used Sublime Text as a text editor, this is interesting. TIL...